# Iframe issue need to decrease pageload time

Tags: javascript, php, html, pageload, page-load-time

I have a website (wordpress) which has a few thousand posts on it. A post will look like this:

```
[tab:source1]
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/U3rKPexoEcA" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
[tab:source2]
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/60718161?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&badge=0" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
<p><a href="https://vimeo.com/60718161">HOW TO SHARPEN PENCILS</a> from <a href="https://vimeo.com/pricefilms">Pricefilms</a> on <a href="https://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.</p>
[tab:source3]
<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://www.worldstarhiphop.com/embed/100588" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

My page load times are sometimes in the double digits. I understand why this occurs but I'm not sure how to fix it. I want to fix it with either:

```
Iframe setTimeout()
```

Or:
Dynamic Asynch Iframe that looks like this:

```
<script>
(function(d){
  var iframe = d.body.appendChild(d.createElement('iframe')),
  doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

  // style the iframe with some CSS
  iframe.style.cssText = "position:absolute;width:200px;height:100px;left:0px;";

  doc.open().write('<body onload="' + 
  'var d = document;d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].' + 
  'appendChild(d.createElement(\'script\')).src' + 
  '=\'\/path\/to\/file\'">');

  doc.close(); //iframe onload event happens

  })(document);
</script>
```

With either method how would I apply this globally to all iframes across the entire website? I don't think it's possible to change each iframe individually.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you better replace all iframes with your desired loading solution in php template before output. Use regexp, like this `<iframe.*src="([^"]*)".*\/iframe>`. I suppose replacing iframes width div containing loading gif and data-src attribute with real iframe url is good solution. Then use js load iframes inside div, after page loaded.